# trouble with this case statement Ruby

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

Can someone help me understand how to write this case statement properly its not working and as a NOOB I have no idea how to fix it:

```
def hide_link?(link, mailing)
  case link
  when 'edit' &&  ['sent', 'sending', 'archived'].include?(mailing.status)
    return true
  when 'send_schedule' &&  ['sent', 'sending', 'archived'].include?(mailing.status)
    return true
  when 'archive' && ['archived'].include?(mailing.status)
    puts "I should be in here"
    return true
  else 'dashboard' && ['sending', 'draft'].include?(mailing.status)
    return true
  end
end
```

Basically I want to return true when the link matches certain criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that if link doesn't match these criterias the method should return false. Thus:

```
def hide_link?(link, mailing)
  case link
  when 'edit'
    ['sent', 'sending', 'archived'].include?(mailing.status)
  when 'send_schedule'
    ['sent', 'sending', 'archived'].include?(mailing.status)
  when 'archive'
    puts "I should be in here"
    ['archived'].include?(mailing.status)
  when 'dashboard'
    ['sending', 'draft'].include?(mailing.status)
  else
    false
  end
end
```

The construction `[...].include?(mailing.status)` has result `true` or `false` which will be returned as a result of `hide_link?` method.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `return`.

```
link = "fred"
case link
  when "fred"
    true
  else
    false
end
```

`case` will return the value itself which will then be passed to the method.

Refactor of megas's version:

```
def hide_link?(link, mailing)
  statuses_to_hide = case link
    when 'edit', 'send_schedule'
      %w{sent sending archived}
    when 'archive'
      %w{archived}
    when 'dashboard'
      %w{sending draft}
    else
      []
    end
  statuses_to_hide.include?(mailing.status)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditions in the case statement all follow the same form, which suggest that there is an opportunity to eliminate some repetition, and to [separate policy from implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024135/separate-policy-from-mechanism-what-does-it-mean).  The *policy* is the set of conditions under which the link should be hidden:

```
WHEN_TO_HIDE_LINK = [
  ['edit', %w(sent sending archived)],
  ['send_schedule', %w(sent sending archived)],
  ['archive', %w(archived)],
  ['dashboard', %w(sending draft)],
]
```

The *implementation* is the code that applies the policy:

```
def hide_link?(link, mailing)
  WHEN_TO_HIDE_LINK.any? do |link_value, mailing_statuses|
    link_value == link && mailing_statuses.include?(mailing.status)
  end
end
```

Explanations below the fold.

---

**%w**

%w is a way to specify a list of strings without typing all those quotes and commas.  This:

```
%w(sent sending archived)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
['sent', 'sending', 'archived']
```

**any?**

[Enumerable#any?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) passes each element of the array to the block (the bit between the `do` and the `end`).  If the block ever returns *truthy*, then the result of `any?` is true; otherwise, the value of `any?` is false.

**array decomposition**

Did you notice that although each element of `WHEN_TO_HIDE_LINK` is an array, the block passed to `any?` does not take an array?  You might expect that you'd have to do this:

```
WHEN_TO_HIDE_LINK.any? do |when_to_hide|
  link_value = when_to_hide[0]
  mailing_statuses = when_to_hide[1]
  ...
```

but Ruby will decompose array into parts for you.  Here's one way to do it:

```
WHEN_TO_HIDE_LINK.any? do |when_to_hide|
  link_value, mailing_statuses = when_to_hide
  ...
```

When there is an array on the right side of the `=` and comma-separated variables on the left, Ruby decomposes the array into its elements and assigns them to the variables separately.

But Ruby can make things even easier:

```
WHEN_TO_HIDE_LINK.any? do |link_value, mailing_statuses|
  ...
```

This is equivalent to either of the preceding two fragments.